# melt multiple id.vars as all columns excluded from a list

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d"),
                var1=c(2,4,4,5),
                var2=c(5,6,2,6),
                var3=c(5,3,2,1))

msr<-c("var1", "var2","var3")

melt(df1,
 id.vars = -c(msr), #problem here
 measure.vars = c(msr))
```

I have a dataframe similiar to this, except with a large number of id.vars. I would like to include all of them and the easiest way would be to simply exclude columns used as measure.vars. However, I seem to be unable to this.

I have also tried:

```
ids<-df1[,-c(msr)] #why can't I exclude?
melt(df1,
     id.vars = c(ids), #problem here
     measure.vars = c(msr))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try: `library(tidyverse) df1 %>%
  gather(key, value, msr)`

Comment: Or replace `-c(msr)` with `names(dat)[-match(msr, names(dat))]`. Also, `c()` around msr is unecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `id.vars` argument of `reshape2::melt` function if you know list of columns for `measure.vars`. The `melt` function is very much flexible in that sense:

> Meaning if `id.vars` is `blank` then all `non-measured` variables will
>   be used as `id.vars`. Similarly, if `id.vars` is provided and
>   `measure.vars` is `blank` then all `non id.vars` will be used as
>   `measure.vars`.

Hence, change needed to correct OP's use of `melt` is:

```
library(reshape2)

msr<-c("var1", "var2","var3")

melt(df1, measure.vars = msr)  # id.vars will be all non-measured variables

#    id variable value
# 1   a     var1     2
# 2   b     var1     4
# 3   c     var1     4
# 4   d     var1     5
# 5   a     var2     5
# 6   b     var2     6
# 7   c     var2     2
# 8   d     var2     6
# 9   a     var3     5
# 10  b     var3     3
# 11  c     var3     2
# 12  d     var3     1
```

**Data:**

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d"),
                var1=c(2,4,4,5),
                var2=c(5,6,2,6),
                var3=c(5,3,2,1))
```